# Azure AD B2C login not working when app is pushed to Azure service

Tags: asp.net, azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Asp.Net core web app using Azure AD B2C for login. When I test it locally using the reply url `http://localhost:54678/` in both the app and the settings in the Azure portal it works fine, I can login and the user is authenticated with no problem. But once I update the reply urls to the url of the app which is `https://musdqapp.com`, I start getting an error of:

> message=Correlation failed

This is how i have set up the `OpenIdConnectOptions`

```cs
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions()
 {
   Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp" + "/ticketfortb2c.onmicrosoft.com" + "/B2C_1_ticket-fort" + "/v2.0",
   ClientId = "client_is", //the id of the b2c application
   ClientSecret = "secret",
   ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
   UseTokenLifetime = true,
   PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://musdqapp.com/",
   Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
   {
     OnTokenValidated = SecurityTokenValidated,
     OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure
   }
 });
```

And on the Azure portal I have the reply url of the B2C app set to `https://musdqapp.com/signin-oidc`

Comment: Try setting the reply url to "https://musdqapp.com". The registered reply URL's should match the redirect url in the request exactly.

Comment: There should be more to that error message, can you please include the full error message and the correlation id.

Comment: Also, you should keep your ClientSecrets, well, secret. So I'd suggest you don't post them in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

The reply URL must be https://musdqapp.com/ without the "signin-oidc". Reply URL and Redirect URI should match.

See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b) for more information.